# Trigonometric version of Schur's inequality

Tags: inequality, trigonometry, schur-inequality

Let $\alpha+\beta+\gamma=\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $t>0$, prove that

> $$\cos^t{(\alpha)}\sin{(\alpha-\beta)}\sin{(\alpha-\gamma)}+\cos^t{(\beta)}\sin{(\beta-\alpha)}\sin{(\beta-\gamma)}+\cos^t{(\gamma)}\sin{(\gamma-\alpha)}\sin{(\gamma-\beta)}\ge 0.$$

This result (which is actually a conjecture) has been suggested by equations $(14)$ and $(15)$ [here](https://geometriadominicana.blogspot.com/2022/12/areal-property-of-circumcircle-mid-arc.html).

**Note**. I am not an expert in inequalities, so this is probably known, obvious, or can be further generalized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\alpha, \beta, \gamma \ge 0$:

WLOG, assume that $\alpha \ge \beta \ge \gamma$.
Let $x := \alpha - \beta$ and $y := \beta - \gamma$. Then $x, y \ge 0$ and $x + y \le \pi/2$ and $\alpha = \gamma + x + y, \beta = \gamma + y$.

The desired inequality is written as
$$\cos^t(\gamma + x + y)\sin x\, \sin (x + y)
- \cos^t(\gamma + y) \sin x\, \sin y
+ \cos^t \gamma\, \sin(x + y)\,\sin y \ge 0 $$
or
$$\cos^t(\gamma + x + y)\sin x\, \sin (x + y)
+ [\cos^t \gamma\, \sin(x + y) - \cos^t(\gamma + y) \sin x]\sin y \ge 0$$
which is true since $\cos^t \gamma \ge \cos^t(\gamma + y)$ and $\sin (x+y)\ge \sin x$.

Comment: Thank you very much. I wonder if this version would be as useful for solving other trig inequalities as the classical Schur's version. Also, I wonder if a generalization is possible.

Comment: @EmmanuelJoséGarcía You are welcome. I think it is related to Page 5 last line in https://www.cip.ifi.lmu.de/~grinberg/VornicuS.pdf

Comment: You are right. Thanks for the reference.